# as.matrix on named list returning matrix with typeof "list"

Tags: r

I'm trying to turn a named list in R into a column matrix with row names such as:

```
my_matrix = as.matrix(list(Row1Name=1,Row2Name=2,Row3Name=3))
```

This seems straight forward enough and even appears to work (see output below). Unfortunately, despite appearances this is not a normal numeric matrix but rather a list matrix. Normally I wouldn't care but in this case I'd like to use apply to perform row based calculations. Is there an easy solution other than ugly code to manually convert my list to a matrix?

[image: Full R Console Interactive Output]

Comment: You are constructing a `list` .  Instead you can directly create a matrix with `matrix(1:3, nrow = 3, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(paste0("Row", 1:3, "Name"), NULL))`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I know I can, I mention that in my question. What I'm interested to know is if I can do this without manually creating a matrix. What you suggest I simply don't think is as readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to construct from a `list`, `unlist` and then wrap with `as.matrix`

```
my_matrix <- as.matrix(unlist(lst1))
```

Now, there won't be any errors

```
apply(my_matrix, 1, sum)
```

But, there are vectorized options

```
rowSums(my_matrix)
```

and also as there is a single column, probably this won't be needed (may be the example is a simple one)

where

```
lst1 <- list(Row1Name=1,Row2Name=2,Row3Name=3)
```

Comment: That's it! I didn't even know you could do named vectors. I'd never even tried. Thanks! I'll accept your answer once the 10 time limit is up.